# How can I set a custom error message from a variable directly from the RequiredFieldValidator?

Tags: c#, .net

Tried with this :

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
     ID="rqrNome" 
     runat="server" 
     Display="Dynamic" 
     ControlToValidate="txtNome" 
     ErrorMessage="<%= myVar %>">
              &nbsp;*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

but seems that this is not possible. I'll get rid about go to the .ascx.cs and use for each validator

```
rqrNome.ErrorMessage = myVar;
```

sometimes too many variables to check. I'd like to put directly on the .ascx.

Is it possible?

I think I cannot remove `runat="server"` tag from the RequiredFieldValidator

Comment: Your tag isn't well formed. There's content after the closing ""s of the ErrorMessage attribute and no mention of myVar. Probably better if you stick up a more complete description.

Comment: @Brian Scott : ? tags are well formed. If I put this code I get the error `Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
     ID="rqrNome" 
     runat="server" 
     Display="Dynamic" 
     ControlToValidate="txtNome">
<%= myVar %>&nbsp;*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Update:

Ok, well how about using the above to set the text via your 'myVar'. Then include the following linq query to iterate all of the requiredfieldvalidtors on the page;

```
var requiredFieldValidators = 
from validators in this.Page.Controls.Cast<Control>()
where validator is RequiredFieldValidator
select (RequiredFieldValidator)validator;
```

Then iterate all the validators setting their ErrorMessage to become equal to their text property which has already been set correctly.

```
requiredFieldValidators.ToList().ForEach(c => c.ErrorMessage = c.Text);
```

Comment: This is not the `ErrorMessage`

Comment: I'd like to use ErrorMessage, so on client, with ValidationSummary, I can show my custom alert message (and the data is not sent to the server).

Comment: No man! Is not what I'm looking for. In fact I'd like, when I config each RequiredFieldValidator, set a custom variable to each. Directly not on ascx.cs

Comment: @markZZZ: But that's what's happening already. You're setting your 'myVar1', 'myVar2', 'myVar3' .... to each requiredfieldvalidtors text. The script then simply updates each requiredfieldvalidator's ErrorMessage to match the Text.

Comment: Yeah, but in need to do this on ascx.cs, and I'll get rid about THIS! Would be nice set up the variable directly on the ascx page...